# Offer Customer-Branded Sign-In Experience for SaaS Multi-Tenant Application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Exploring options IAM in front of a White Labeled SaaS solution.  In a nutshell, my customers would hang an 'Apply Now' button off their web property which would link in to a subdomain of my own, for example, https://.mydomain.com when the user lands there I want to discover which of my clients was the referring domain and I want to show their logo on the page and company name.  Some requirements:

1. I'm hoping to use one single deployment because traffic volumes aren't very high so trying to avoid a complex deployment strategy.
2. I'm targeting a specific industry and customers regularly shop across providers so ideally their account gets created in a central directory and is transferable across tenants.  For example, Customer visits Tenant1 and clicks creates an account.  I want to prompt them for an email address and then check if they already have an account.  In this scenario they don't yet so they complete the SignUpSignIn flow for a Local account.  Once in to the system they prepare their request and submit it.  Later that same day they go to Tenant2 and click 'Apply Now'.  I want to detect that they came from Tenant2 and now show Tenant2's Logo and Company name and again ask for an email.  When they key it in I want to indicate they already have an account on the system and let them login where they will see their existing request and now can submit it to another possible provider.
3. My Tenants customers are coming from the Internet but my Tenants are Corporations likely with their own existing Directories so I have to be able to offer them an OIDC connection option to access their repository with submitted requests.  I've read about Home Realm Discovery and think that may be the way to solve for this but it looks rather difficult to maintain for many clients.

I've looked at Azure AD B2C and I haven't been able to find a solid reference application that shows how I might achieve this.  I'm starting to think I may have to create a separate Custom Policy for every tenant and then pass a domain_hint to select the right user experience on the front-end, is that the correct way to go here?  Is this even possible as one deployment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is dynamic page customisation, one policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-dynamic-custom-page-content-uri

You probably do want HRD, which might negate the need for donain_hint. Depends which you prefer/need. Could even have both in one policy depending on whether domain_hint is passed in.

“ Later that same day they go to Tenant2 and click 'Apply Now'. I want to detect that they came from Tenant2 and now show Tenant2's Logo and Company name and again ask for an email. When they key it in I want to indicate they already have an account on the system and let them login where they will see their existing request and now can submit it to another possible provider.” -> deserves its own question.